How to integrate custom php (custom built modules) with nginx unit?
In future we are planning integrating nginx-unit with php (custom extensions, modules)
So now, Im wondering how to do it
Should we

get unit-php prebuilt docker image and modify afterwards (compile and install additional stuff)
get minimal image and do php compilation from scratch?
get base image, compile unit, compile php and link them?

Was just wondering how to link them

Will answer here shortly (to my question):

Configure (with --enable-embed option to generate .so) and compile wanted version of php
Configure unit with php module pointing to previously compiled so library file and php-config
Compile and install unit - thats it
https://unit.nginx.org/howto/source

